# How to define xml response in YUI autocomplete

Tags: java, html, yui

I am using YUI autocomplete with XML datasource. Its working fine but I have a small query.
How can we filter suggestion field from response xml. Suppose XML response have following structure

`<books>

<book>

<title> some_title </title>

<author> Some_author </author>

</book>

</books>`

How can we configure output to show only `<title>` or `<author>` in auto suggestion list ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some help from  [YUI forum](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=89&t=7716&p=24570#p24570)  
Hope it will help others :)